# Agregar pipe a formControl angular2 Formularios Reactivos

Tags: angularjs-2.0

mi pregunta es esa , como puedo agregarle un pipe como eso a un formulario reactivo , para casos no reactivos , he visto que se puede hacer de la siguiente manera.

```
<input [ngModel]="item.value | useMyPipeToFormatThatValue" 
      (ngModelChange)="item.value=$event" name="inputField" type="text" />
```

Ahora estoy usando los form reactivos de angular2 , y me surgio esa duda , este es mi codigo html.

```
<form [formGroup]='fb'>
    <input type="text" [formControl]='searchTerm'>
    <button (click)="formClick()">FormClick</button>
    <input type="text" [formControl]="masterValue">
</form>

<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let user of users">
        {{user.name}}
    </li>
</ul>

<p>{{master | masterPipe}}</p>
```

mi MasterPipe.ts

```
    export class MasterPipe implements PipeTransform{
    transform(master:string){
        const market=4;
        let oculto=master.slice(0,-market);
        let visible=master.slice(-market);
        let a:string=oculto.replace(/./g,'*')+visible;
        return a;
    }
}
```

Quiero agregarle ese pipe al input con el formControl=masterValue ,algo asi como esta en la linea mas abajo pero en el mismo input.

```
<p>{{master | masterPipe}}</p>
```

Comment: ¿Ya solucionaste el problema?

Answer (score 1):

Podrias suscribirte a los cambios del valor del input y cada vez que se lance el evento, pasarle la misma lógica de filtrado que tendrías en el input, pero teniendolo en un método dentro de ese componente.